# Stuck at Flask tutorial step 3

Tags: python, sqlite, python-2.7, flask

Following Flask tutorial, running Win 7, Python 2.7.3, virtualenv, and I am stuck in Step 3: Creating The Database http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/tutorial/dbinit/#tutorial-dbinit

> Such a schema can be created by piping the schema.sql file into the sqlite3 command as follows:
>
> ```
> sqlite3 /tmp/flaskr.db < schema.sql
> ```

How to run this command, because CMD < venv > returns:

> "sqlite3" is not recognized as internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Is this step necessary?

Folder Project, 2 files schema.sql and flaskr.py.

**schema.sql**

```
drop table if exists entries;
create table entries (
  id integer primary key autoincrement,
  title string not null,
  text string not null
);
```

**flaskr.py**

```
# all the imports
import sqlite3
from flask import Flask, request, session, g, redirect, url_for, \
abort, render_template, flash
from contextlib import closing
# configuration
DATABASE = '/tmp/flaskr.db'
DEBUG = True
SECRET_KEY = 'development key'
USERNAME = 'admin'
PASSWORD = 'default'

# create our little application :)
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(__name__)
app.config.from_envvar('FLASKR_SETTINGS', silent=True)


def connect_db():
    return sqlite3.connect(app.config['DATABASE'])

def init_db():
    with closing(connect_db()) as db:
        with app.open_resource('schema.sql') as f:
            db.cursor().executescript(f.read())
        db.commit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

**`< venv > python`**

```
>>> from flaskr import init_db
>>> init_db()
Trackeback <most recent call last>:
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "flaskr.py", line 24, in init_db
  with closing (connect_db()) as db: 
File "flaskr.py", line 21, in connect_db
return sqlite3.connect(app.config['DATABASE'])
sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database.
```

Comment: The command line tool is called `sqlite3.exe` on Windows.

Comment: The `sqlite3.OperationalError` would be caused by SQLite not being able to *write* the configured database file (it creates one if it doesn't exist yet).

Comment: Downloaded sqlite3.exe, sqlitie> sqlite3 /tmp/flaskr.db < schema.sql        returns                     ...>   any help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are confused between Windows and UNIX filesystems.

Find out where `sqllite.exe` file exists on the computer. lets say it is in `C:\sqllite`. Then you also need to determine where you will create the database file. `/tmp/flaskr.db` is for the UNIX filesystem. On windows, you should provide the exact path or in your current working directory. lets say it is `C:\flasktutorial`.

To be safe, you might want to create a blank `flaskr.db` file first.

```
Open a notepad and create the blank file at `C:\flasktutorial\flaskr.db`
```

Now you can run:

```
C:\sqllite\sqllite.exe C:\flasktutorial\flaskr.db < schema.sql
```

Also make sure that in your flaskr.py file, change the DATABASE to:

```
DATABASE = 'C:\flasktutorial\flaskr.db'
```

Comment: Change working directory for the sake of instruction. What am I doing wrong?  pic related:                   http://s8.postimg.org/j6oovqlx1/picture.png

Comment: where is the schema.sql file stored ? Is it also in the current working directory ? I also updated my answer to create the flaskr.db file first as a safety measure.

Comment: ok then try creating the flaskr.db blank file first and then run the command?

Comment: your latest screenshot shows schema.sql is in C:\flasktutorial folder but you are running the command in C:\sqllite folder. Either copy the schema.sql in C:\sqllite folder or call it as C:\flasktutorial\schema.sql

Answer (score 4):

Did you activate virtualenv and installed flask?

flask should have sqlite3 by default. I got following error though:

```
 File "flaskr.py", line 26, in connect_db
  return sqlite3.connect(app.config['DATABASE'])
sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file`
```

To fix that I had to do the following (in Windows):

1. Change `DATABASE = '/tmp/flaskr.db'` to `DATABASE = '.\\tmp\\flaskr.db'`
2. Create tmp folder in current folder (flaskr)
3. Create an empty flaskr.db file in tmp

After that it's working for me.

Comment: Thanks so much for this, had the exact same problem and this worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

As you can observe from the error logs, the error is coming while connecting DB

> sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database.

And since this step failed for you,

> sqlite3 /tmp/flaskr.db < schema.sql

You can easily interpret that **this step is necessary**.
Now to solve this error, simply you have to install sqlite3, In ubuntu you can install sqlite3 as,

> apt-get install sqlite3

After installation your program will work fine as expected.

Comment: This is on *Windows*. And SQLite *creates* the database file if it doesn't yet exist (albeit without the schema), so something else is wrong.

Comment: This was the answer in my case except used `pip install sqlite3` on `OS X`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if these tips are directly applicable to the PO, but they landed me here, so maybe it will be helpful.

Be sure to check the `README` file within the `flaskr` directory which specifies running `flask --app=flaskr initdb` from the command line.

If this returns `AttributeError: 'Flask' object has no attribute 'cli'`, it may be due to `click` not being installed.

If the command returns `flask: command not found`, it may be due to having an older version of Flash installed, which is what `pip install flask` does.

As of today this command `pip install https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/tarball/master`, will install the most recent version.

Answer (score 0):

For linux user only:

First you install Sqlite3 from [here](https://www.sqlite.org/download.html).

After installation you need to create a file called **flaskr.db**,location of this file is to be */myproject/venv/bin/flaskr/tmp* .

Next step is run command

```
sqlite3 /home/ddserver/myproject/venv/bin/flaskr/tmp/flaskr.db<schema.sql
```

I took file address from home.

Next step is start python shell, run this code

```
>>> from flaskr import init_db
>>> init_db()
```

Thats it.